# make Regex to find and replace "#" and avoid replacing "&#"

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

Is it possible to find just # in below string by regex:
`<p>userName:</p><p dir="ltr">&#39;It&#39;s so cl#an ## # the coast.&#39;</p>`
I want select and replace `#` with other word but avoid replacing &#.
final String could something like this (replace # with _):
`<p>userName:</p><p dir="ltr">&#39;It&#39;s so cl_an __ _ the coast.&#39;</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace on the following pattern:

```regex
(?<!&)#
```

This would match any hash symbol which is *not* preceded by ampersand.  Here is a sample code:

```kotlin
val input = "<p>userName:</p><p dir=\"ltr\">&#39;It&#39;s so cl#an ## # the coast.&#39;</p>"
val output = input.replace("(?<!&)#".toRegex(), "_")
println(output)
```

This prints:

```
<p>userName:</p><p dir="ltr">&#39;It&#39;s so cl_an __ _ the coast.&#39;</p>
```

Side note: Generally try to avoid manipulating HTML/XML or other possibly nested content using regex.  It happens to work with your current input though, given that there are no nested tags.